# Using xpath in rvest to scrape content between two h5 headings?

Tags: html, r, xpath, web-scraping, rvest

I'm in the process of extracting content from local html files by using rvest. I would like to extract a certain segment of content between two h5 headings, the only 'specifying' detail being the textual title of the initial h5 heading. The problem is, that the documents vary in their headings – both the IDs and the textual content are subject to many variations – the only exception being the textual title ”Details” I’m interested in. Please see an example of the document structure:

```
<div id=”document”>
<h3>Title of the document</h3>
<h4 id=”id11111”>Focus of the document</h4>
<p>This document focuses on…</p>
<p>And also…</p>
<h5 id=”id22222”> 1. Introduction </h5>
<p>Text here.</p>
<h6 id=”33333”> 1.1 Preliminary introduction </h6>
<p> Text here. </p>
<h5 id=”id44444”> 2. Details </h5>
<p>Text here.</p>
<h6 id=”id55555”> 2.1 Details about A </h6>
<p> Text here. </p>
<h6 id=”id66666”> 2.2 Details about B </h6>
<p> Text here. </p>
<h5 id=”id77777”> 3. Timeline </h5>
<p>Text here.</p>
<h6 id=”id88888”> 3.1 Timeline A </h5>
<p>Text here.</p>
</div>
```

From the preceding example, I'd like to extract only, and only, the content from h5 tag with id44444, textual title "2. Details" until the next h5 heading (h5 id 77777, 3, Timeline).

I've managed to pinpoint my scraping to begin from the wished h5 tag (see example below) by using contains and following-sibling::* but it returns all siblings until the end of the document, whereas my goal is to stop the return to the following h5 heading.

I haven’t figured out how to use ”preceding-sibling”, because the following h5 tag does not have a standard id, xpath or textual content and the order of the headings is not standard. The h5 headings can appear with a varying order.

```
#loading rvest
library('rvest')


files <- list.files(”C:/htmldocuments”)

#performing the scrape
scraping <- sapply(files, function (x)
read_html(x, encoding = "utf-8") %>%
html_nodes(xpath = '//h5[contains(., ”Details”)]/following-sibling::*') %>%
html_text())
```

This returns results which begin at the correct place, but how can it be stopped to the first following h5 tag after the h5 tag of "Details"? The id and title of the following h5 tag vary and thus is unknown.

I've reviewed multiple similar questions – the answers often point to using preceding-sibling – however I can't seem to figure out how to use it, as I have no way of knowing what the following h5 is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following XPath expression :

```
//p[preceding::*[1][contains(.,"Details")]]
```

This will select all `p` elements which are preceded by a heading element which contains the word "Details".

Output : 3 nodes

[image: Nodes]

If you need to keep the headings, you can use :

```
//*[preceding::*[1][contains(.,"Details")] or contains(text(),"Details")]
```

Output : 6 nodes

Comment: Thank you @E.Wiest for the reply. I tried your solution and it worked! Is your solution 'universal' in a sense that it also applies to cases where there are several chapters of text below h6s?

`<h5 id=”id44444”> 2. Details </h5>
<p>Text here.</p>
<p>Text here.</p>
<h6 id=”id55555”> 2.1 Details about A </h6>
<p> Text here. </p>
<p>Text here.</p>
<p>Text here.</p>
<p>Text here.</p>
<h6 id=”id66666”> 2.2 Details about B </h6>
<p> Text here. </p>
<p>Text here.</p>
<h5 id=”id77777”> 3. Timeline </h5>`

In these kind of docs the results were partial much to my surprise...

Comment: In that case you can use : `//p[preceding::h5[1][contains(.,"Details")]]`. Output : https://framapic.org/SF45n58G7sVt/1lgVOeH6VEfL.PNG